# ¿Como puedo eliminar todo los archivos relacionados con mysql en un servidor Linux-Oracle 7.9?

Tags: mysql, linux, variables-de-configuración

Estaba configurando un servidor Linux-Oracle que nos entregaron en la universidad para desarrollar un trabajo, y mientras realizaba esta introduje un comando que encontré en internet y ahora no me deja iniciar el servicio.
Ya he probado con remover la instalación y otras cosas mas.
[image: Error al intentar encender el servidor de Mysql]

[image: Como me sale el status del servidor]

[image: Mysqld.log]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

- sudo service mysql start
- sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
- systemctl status mysql.service
- sudo systemctl start mysqld

Si tu problema persiste, puedes utilizar este comando para visualizar mejor el error:

- journalctl -xe

Para eliminar el programa y sus archivos intenta con:

- sudo -i
- service mysql stop
- killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
- apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
- apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
- apt-get autoclean
- deluser --remove-home mysql
- delgroup mysql
- rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld
- updatedb
- exit